# Full Calendar compatibility fail?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

When I try to load fullCalendar with the latest jQuery 1.10.x , it shows nothing : 
http://jsfiddle.net/vwasteels/JWs5j/1/

```
// not working...
```

but if I downgrade jQuery to 1.7.2 , it works :
http://jsfiddle.net/vwasteels/JWs5j/2/

I don't understand since it's written on FullCalendar site :

> Browser Testing
>
> FullCalendar has been tested with:
>
> jQuery 1.10.2 / jQuery UI 1.10.3 Firefox, Chrome, Safari, IE 7+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're not using the latest version of FullCalendar.

I took the latest one from [FullCalendar's site](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/download/) and it works with both `1.x` and `2.x` version of jQuery: [DEMO of 1.x](http://jsfiddle.net/6Qp72/)

Answer (score 3):

If you crack open the console, you'll see they're attempting to use a method named `curCSS` which doesn't exist and is throwing an error.

Also, you're not using the latest version of the calendar. You've got version 1.5.3 in your fiddle, but the latest is 1.6.4, which works just fine with jQuery 1.10.2:

http://jsfiddle.net/JWs5j/3/